# Flash card template fuctions according to her own will

Tags: actions-on-google

I made an action on Google where the assistant asks a question regarding country name and the user tells a country name to describe its demography. But the Flash Card template I used knows the answer and doesn't takes user's answer. I want to make it user driven and not assistant driven.

I tried other templates but none of them solves this.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the conversation flow?  Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MaxWiederholt yes, the conversation goes like this => Assistant - "Which country you want to search for?"; User - Tells name of specific country ; After this the Assistant should give details of the country name given by the user. But what it is doing is that it already knows the answer to the question it has asked, so there's no way user can go for his choice of answer (much like quiz game). This I want to change to user specific answers.